# Problem with Array<String> resource files

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

In my project I use resource files with arrays of strings in them, then I get a single String and check if it is in this array, which doesn't work
Here's some code:

//putting an array from resource file into variable

`val categoryOne: Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.categoryOne_array)`

`val values: Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.categories_array)`

//getting the string from spinner

```
        var text = "blank"
        spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                text = values[p2]
                Log.d("ASDASD", text)
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                return
            }
        }
```

//checking if string is in the array

```
        var currentGroup = "0"
        if(categoryOne.contains(text)){
            currentGroup = "1"
        }
```

No matter what the value of "text" is, value of currentGroup stays 0

Here's the resource files also:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="categories_array">
        <item>Бег. ОРУ</item>
        <item>Кросс</item>
        <item>Игры</item>
        <item>Сил. упр.</item>
        <item>Скор. эст.</item>
        <item>Плавание</item>
        <item>Борьба</item>

        <item>Имит. упр</item>
        <item>Упр. со скакалкой</item>
        <item>Упр. с эспандером</item>
        <item>Бой с тенью</item>
        <item>Имит. упр. с утяж.</item>
        <item>Упр. с медболом</item>
        <item>Прыжковая работа</item>
        <item>Стрейчинг</item>

        <item>Отр. со слабым парт.</item>
        <item>Отр. с сильным парт.</item>

        <item>Слабый партнер</item>
        <item>Сильный партнер</item>

        <item>Мешки</item>
        <item>Подушки</item>
        <item>Груши</item>
        <item>Лапы</item>

        <item>Вольные бои</item>
        <item>Спаринг</item>
        <item>Соревн. бои</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="categoryOne_array">
        <item>Бег. ОРУ</item>
        <item>Кросс</item>
        <item>Игры</item>
        <item>Сил. упр.</item>
        <item>Скор. эст.</item>
        <item>Плавание</item>
        <item>Борьба</item>

        <item>Имит. упр</item>
        <item>Упр. со скакалкой</item>
        <item>Упр. с эспандером</item>
        <item>Бой с тенью</item>
        <item>Имит. упр. с утяж.</item>
        <item>Упр. с медболом</item>
        <item>Прыжковая работа</item>
        <item>Стрейчинг</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I hope I shared all code relevant to the question, if I didn't, please tell me and I shall provide it

Comment: Please double check array contains this data by ```Log.d("TAG", `My array: ${categoryOne.toString()} and search ${text}`)```. Correctness of this piece of code looks ok, the issue might be in data set and searched word.

Comment: @Gleichmut thank you for the comment! I figured it out: if statements were executed before the value of "text" was ever changed, i had to move it to onClickListener on the button for it to work perfectly fine. Thanks again for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is "contains" is also case-sensitive. You have to use ignore case.
Something like

```
val array:Array<String> = resources.getStringArray(R.array.yourarray);
val test = "two"
for(item in array) {
    if(item.equals(test, ignoreCase = true)) {
       return true
     }
 }
```